# Show hide drop down and image replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need a little help setting up a jquery event, basically when a user clicks the header div the header expands to show a list and an image that has a 0 in it changes to an X to close it and it alternates depending on what is selected.  I'm using a plugin called show_hide.  Anyway to add this functionality?

[jsfidddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YXmUk/1/)

Comment: Please post your relevant code, or better, a http://jsfiddle.net demonstrating it.

Comment: basically something like [link](http://jsfiddle.net/YXmUk/) for the list and I'm not sure the plugin location.  But basically when title clicked image switch and expose list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/YXmUk/5/

```
$('#exposed').hide();
$('a.expose').on('click',function(){
    $('#exposed').toggle(500);
    if($('#exposed').is(':visible')){
        $(this).find('img').attr('src','cross.png');
    }else{
        $(this).find('img').attr('src','open-circle.png');
    }
});
```